# Multer can not get the upload form data in Express 4

Tags: express, form-data, multer

I'm using Ajax to upload the form data. The output of multer(req.file, req.body) is always `undefined`/`{}`;

My server code:

```
import multer from 'multer';
import post from './router/api_post';

var upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'});

app.use('/api/post', upload.single('thumb') , post);
```

and the `api_post` router file:

```
import express from 'express';
var router = express.Router();

router
    .post('/', (req, res, next) => {
        console.log("POST POST");
        var post = {};
        console.log(req.body);
        console.log(req.file);
    });

export default router;
```

the output of `req.body` is `{}` and of req.file`is`undefined`.

I use react on the browser side and upload data via ajax:

```
  savePost(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var editor = this.refs.editorDom.getDOMNode();
    var ajaxReq = new AjaxRequest();
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('post_id', this.state.post_id);
    formData.append('title', this.state.title);
    formData.append('author', this.state.author);
    formData.append('digest', this.state.digest);
    formData.append('content', editor.innerHTML);
    formData.append('content_source_url', this.state.content_source_url);
    formData.append('create_time', new Date());
    formData.append('thumb', this.state.thumb);
    ajaxReq.send('post', '/api/post', ()=>{
      if(ajaxReq.getReadyState() == 4 && ajaxReq.getStatus() == 200) {
        var result = JSON.parse(ajaxReq.getResponseText());
        if(result.ok == 1) {
          console.log("SAVE POST SUCCESS");
        }
      }
    }, '', formData);
  }
```

The `savePost()` is callback of a button's event listener. I did upload data successfully with formidable. I just replaced the formidable with multer but can not get it.

I didn't set the content-type property. I found it in the header is 
`, multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary76s9Cg74EW1B94D9`

The `form`'s HTML is

```
<form id="edit-panel" data-reactid=".ygieokt1c0.1.0.1.0.1">
  <div id="title" class="form-group" data-reactid=".ygieokt1c0.1.0.1.0.1.0">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="" data-reactid=".ygieokt1c0.1.0.1.0.1.0.1">
  </div>
  <div id="author" class="form-group" data-reactid=".ygieokt1c0.1.0.1.0.1.1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" value="" data-reactid=".ygieokt1c0.1.0.1.0.1.1.1">
  </div>
  <div id="thumb" class="form-group" data-reactid=".ygieokt1c0.1.0.1.0.1.2">
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-reactid=".ygieokt1c0.1.0.1.0.1.2.1">
      <input type="file" name="thumb" accept="image/*" data-reactid=".ygieokt1c0.1.0.1.0.1.2.1.0">
      <span data-reactid=".ygieokt1c0.1.0.1.0.1.2.1.1">UPLOAD</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" data-reactid=".ygieokt1c0.1.0.1.0.1.3">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="digest" rows="5" data-reactid=".ygieokt1c0.1.0.1.0.1.3.1"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="rich-text-editor" class="form-group" data-reactid=".ygieokt1c0.1.0.1.0.1.4">
    <div id="editor-div" class="form-control" contenteditable="true" data-reactid=".ygieokt1c0.1.0.1.0.1.4.1"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="content-source-url" class="form-group" data-reactid=".ygieokt1c0.1.0.1.0.1.5">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="content_source_url" value="" data-reactid=".ygieokt1c0.1.0.1.0.1.5.1">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-reactid=".ygieokt1c0.1.0.1.0.1.6">保存并提交</button>
</form>
```

I can output the `thumb`, it's a `File{}` object.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem is the `Content-Type`.

I used `this.request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", postDataType);` to set the `Content-Type` and set the `postDataType` to `''`, then the actual `Content-Type` in header is `, multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary76s9Cg74EW1B94D9` as I mentioned at the first.

You can see there is a comma and a space before the `multipar/form-data`. I have no idea where this comma come from. But anyway, when I remove the comma and space, everything just works fine!